# Identify a Web Button using Selenium

Tags: selenium

How to identify a Button in a Tool Bar in a web page?

Below is the location of the viewer and I need to identify "Open Document" and perform some operation on it?

https://demos.gnostice.com/html5/documentviewer.aspx

How do I identify an element when we don't have much information when we spy and inspect the element?

Comment: Hi Jp Reddy - when you inspect the element, can you show what is revealed? Also, it is not good practice to include a link to an external site as a crucial part of your question: if the site changes or is removed, the value of your question for future readers is lost.

Answer (score 3):

css - `"div[title*='Open document']"`
xpath - `"//div[@title='Open document']"`

Answer (score 0):

```
IWebElement openDoc = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@title='Open document']"));
```

Comment: Hi siva; your code might be correct, but it would be better with some context; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.

Comment: @VinceBowdren, Thanks for the suggestion, will keep in mind when i answer to questions.